# Auto refreshing Partial View, Google Charts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using google's Guages, Bar and Pie charts in MVC4 application,
I have all these listed in a PartialView, and I am calling the partial view from main Index page.And refreshing the partial view for every 30 secs.

after 30 secs I am getting the data, all the scripts and everything in the developer tools but on the page it is disappeared.

my code is as below

Partial View

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<script>
   $(document).ready( function TargetCharts(){

    var gauge;
    var gaugeData;
    var gaugeOptions;
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['gauge'] });
    function drawGauge() {
        gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Success'],
          [5]
        ]);

        gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugeSuccess'));
        gaugeOptions = {
            min: 0,
            max: 8,
            greenFrom: 0,
            greenTo: 5,
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);

    var gauge;
    var gaugeData;
    var gaugeOptions;
    function drawGauge1() {
        gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Failed'],
          [0]
        ]);

        gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugeFailed'));
        gaugeOptions = {
            min: 0,
            max: 8,
            redFrom: 0,
            redTo: 0,
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge1);

    var gauge;
    var gaugeData;
    var gaugeOptions;
    function drawGauge2() {
        gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Running'],
          [2]
        ]);

        gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugeRunning'));
        gaugeOptions = {
            min: 0,
            max: 8,
            greyFrom: 0,
            greyTo: 2,
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge2);

    var gauge;
    var gaugeData;
    var gaugeOptions;
    function drawGauge3() {
        gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Yet To Run'],
          [1]
        ]);

        gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugeYetToRun'));
        gaugeOptions = {
            min: 0,
            max: 8,
            yellowFrom: 0,
            yellowTo: 1,
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge3);

    google.load('visualization', '1');

    function drawVisualization() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            dataTable: [['', 'Brightstar Review' , 'Customer Review' , 'Released From PFO' , 'Dropped To JDE' , 'InProcess To Drop To JDE' , 'NotDropped To JDE'  , 'SalesOrder Created In JDE'  , 'SalesOrder InProcess In JDE' , 'SalesOrder Failed In JDE'  , 'SalesOrder Cancelled In JDE'  , 'SalesOrder Dropped In RB'  , 'SalesOrder Shipped In JDE' ],
                ['', 1, 0,  0,
                        0,  0,
                        0,0,
                        0,  0,
                        0,0,
                         0]],
            options: {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16},width: 350,legend: 'none'
               , tooltip: {isHtml: true,text: 'value' }},
            containerId: 'visualization'
        });
        wrapper.draw();
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Orders Per Day'],
          ['Brightstar Review ' , 1  ],
          ['Customer Review', 0],
          ['Released From PFO' , 0],
          ['Dropped To JDE', 0],
          ['InProcess To Drop To JDE' , 0],
          ['NotDropped To JDE' ,  0],
          ['SalesOrder Created In JDE', 0],
          ['SalesOrder InProcess In JDE', 0],
          ['SalesOrder Failed In JDE' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Cancelled In JDE' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Dropped In RB' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Shipped In JDE' , 0]
        ]);

        var options = {
            //width: 600,
            is3D: true,
            width:350,

            tooltip: {isHtml: true,text: 'value' },
            legend: 'none'
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Orders Per Day'],
          ['Brightstar Review ' , 1  ],
          ['Customer Review', 0],
          ['Released From PFO' , 0],
          ['Dropped To JDE', 0],
          ['InProcess To Drop To JDE' , 0],
          ['NotDropped To JDE' ,  0],
          ['SalesOrder Created In JDE', 0],
          ['SalesOrder InProcess In JDE', 0],
          ['SalesOrder Failed In JDE' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Cancelled In JDE' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Dropped In RB' , 0],
          ['SalesOrder Shipped In JDE' , 0]
        ]);

        var options = {
            //title: 'Cricket Orders',
            //width: 600,
            is3D: true,
            width:350,
            //backgroundColor: '#4C7B86',
            tooltip: {isHtml: true,text: 'value' },
            legend: 'none'
        };
    }

});
</script>


<div class="DashboardSlide">
    <div class="HeaderContainer">
        <div class="CompanyName">
            Target

        </div>
        <div class="CompanyActivity">
            Status: Wait
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
        <div class="chartContainer">
            <div class="CompanyStatus">
                <a href="/SCOJobMonitoring/Index" class="divLegendAction">Jobs</a>
            </div>
            <div class="CompanyTotalStatus">
                Total No. of Jobs: 8
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="GaugeRow">
            <div class="successChart">
                <div id="gaugeSuccess" class=" gauge"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="failedChart">
                <div id="gaugeFailed" class=" gauge"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="runningChart">
                <div id="gaugeRunning" class=" gauge"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="yetToChart">
                <div id="gaugeYetToRun" class="gauge"></div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="borderCharts">
        <div class="HeaderContainerCharts">
            <div class="CompanyOrderStatus">

                <a href="/SCOOrderTracking/Index" class="divLegendAction"> Orders</a>
            </div>
            <div class="CompanyTotalOrderStatus">
                Total No. of Orders : 1
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="ChartRow">
            <div class="pieChartSection">
                <div id="piechart" class="chart"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="barChartSection">
                <div id="visualization" class="chart"></div>
            </div>



            <div class="legenContainerTarget">
                <div class="legendRow">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend blue"></div>   Brightstar Review
                            </td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend red"></div>   Customer Review
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend yellow"></div>   Released From PFO
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend green"></div>   Dropped To JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend purple"></div>   InProcess To Drop To JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend skyblue"></div>   NotDropped To JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend pink"></div>   SalesOrder Created In JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend parrotGreen"></div>   SalesOrder InProcess In JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend cheeryred"></div>   SalesOrder Failed In JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend Navyblue"></div>   SalesOrder Cancelled In JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend violet"></div>   SalesOrder Dropped In RB
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="legend  blueShaded"></div>   SalesOrder Shipped In JDE
                            </td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>


                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="HeaderContainer">
        <div class="CompanyName">
            Cut Off time is at December 19 2013 at 
        </div>
        <div class="CompanyActivity">
            Last Refershed at: 12/20/2013 11:30:00 AM
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main index page

```
<div class="slider" id="slider2">

    <div class="DashboardSlide_parent">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("TargetPartial");}
    </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            // $('.DashboardSlide_parent').html=''; $('.DashboardSlide_parent').load('/SCODashBoard/TargetPartial');
            $.get("/SCODashBoard/TargetPartial", function (data) {
                $(".DashboardSlide_parent").replaceWith(data);
            });
        }, 30000); // every 30 sec
    });

</script>
```

can anyone pleas help me with this issue i really appreciate your help , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use

```
$(".DashboardSlide_parent").html(data);
```

instead of

```
$(".DashboardSlide_parent").replaceWith(data);
```

This will replace just the **contents** of the DashboardSlide_parent div instead of replacing the div itself.